# Anaconda2-4.0.0 installing error -- terminal dead

Tags: bash, ubuntu, vagrant, anaconda

I try this:

```
wget -q http://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -P /tmp
bash Anaconda2-4.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
conda create --name py27conda2_3_0 python=2.7 anaconda=2.3.0
source activate py27conda2_3_0
```

after terminal show this endless and I don't input in terminal:

```
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':  
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
==> default: >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':
```

I don't know how to deal with it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure exactly at which step of your script you need to answer the question, but you can do the following when prompted

```
yes | source activate py27conda2_3_0
```